# How to double attestate intentionally?

Tags: baking, slashing

I'm running a node for and a baker on a public Tezos testnet. My baker is funded, it has baking and endorsing rights.

Now, I'm looking for a neat way to sign and inject two attestations of different blocks at the same level.

The goal is to conduct double attestation on the network and get penalized via slashing as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to do it with TzGO (handle with care):

https://github.com/blockwatch-cc/tzgo/blob/feat/oxford/examples/doublebake/main.go